# How to extract few rows from a Android Cursor and save them in another Cursor?

Tags: android

I was just wondering is it possible to extract few rows from a Android `Cursor` and save them in another `Cursor`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create [a `MatrixCursor`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/MatrixCursor.html) based on data from the original `Cursor`.

Comment: Thanks @CommonsWare Can you point towards an example, tutorial, book or implementation?

Comment: @blackcrow: `MatrixCursor` has a fairly simple API. What specifically are you having problems with?

Comment: I just wanted to look at the example I found here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1882156/using-matrixcursor-and-simplecursoradapter-in-a-listview-with-text-and-images and here http://www.androidadb.com/class/android/database/MatrixCursor.java.html