# Create a cursor from hardcoded array instead of DB

Tags: android, android-cursor

I am trying to make a drag-and-drop list for a little game app I am writing.

There are 6 entries in the list. However the library I added required a Cursor object that talks to a DB. This is overkill for my situation.

Is there a way to create a Cursor object that is based on a memory-based data structure like an array? Is there a way I can used a hard-coded array as my Cursor?

Thanks

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Check out the `MatrixCursor` [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/MatrixCursor.html). Check for instance [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1882156/using-matrixcursor-and-simplecursoradapter-in-a-listview-with-text-and-images).

```
String[] columns = new String[] { "_id", "item", "description" };

MatrixCursor matrixCursor= new MatrixCursor(columns);
startManagingCursor(matrixCursor);

matrixCursor.addRow(new Object[] { 1, "Item A", "...." });

SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = 
        new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.layout_row, matrixCursor, ...);

setListAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: ,@FaddishWorm Thanks for the post. Would you kindly tell me why am I getting "return type for the method is missing" error for startManagingCursor(matrixCursor). What what the solution to fix this. I am using API 19 with minimum api support 8.

Comment: @FaddishWorm: I solved the issue.It was a silly mistake. I was doing the call at the wrong place ie. not inside any method of the class. I managed to work it as getActivity().startManagingCursor(matrixCursor) as the class is a Fragment.

Comment: It would be nice for complete code. IE that layout is something you made??? I'm just testing libraries here and I need a cursor with strings

Answer (score 2):

maybe you can check [MatrixCursor](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/MatrixCursor.html) class that you can call `addRow((Iterable<?> columnValues)` or `addRow(Object[] columnValues)`
hope that will help

Answer (score 1):

use MatrixCursor, instead of addRow() which is not very handy, use builder method newRow()