# How to show the search results in SearchView

Tags: android, searchview

I use toolbar searchview. I catch input result using code:

```
SearchView.OnQueryTextListener queryTextListener = new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {

            return true;
        }
```

When I have the  result I am looking for the similar strings in my excel file. Then I return ArrayList  (search results). And now I need  to show the results in SearchView. How  can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a CursorAdapter associated with your searchview.

```
Searchview.setSuggestionAdapter
```

Helpful link about the usage of a cursor from an array ([Create a cursor from hardcoded array instead of DB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18290864/create-a-cursor-from-hardcoded-array-instead-of-db)).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. When I create SimpleCursorAdapter I need "to" array, but I need to show search result in SearchView. I can't understand how to fill correct SimpleCursorAdapter?

Comment: After you created your SimpleCursorAdapter and associated it with SearchView within the onCreateOptionsMenu, you need to listen to changes using SearchView.setQueryTextListener. Within this Callback (onQueryTextChange) you create a new Cursor from your data and pass the new cursor to the cursoradapter using CursorAdapter.swapCursor.